# Enforce eslint to use original name of default exported module when importing it on some files

Tags: javascript, eslint

Our team always use [eslint](https://eslint.org/) for proper coding standards to follow rules and regulations when it comes to writing codes. We have used [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import). It pretty solves some of our problem but not all of it.

Take this example below:

**Foo.js**

```
const Foo = "Foo"

export default Foo
```

**Foo.jsx**

```
import Bar from './foo'; 
// This still works. 
// It can cause confusion. 
// I want to use the original exported default name Foo instead of Bar
// otherwise show some error in the Code Editor
```

What I want to happen is use the **original name** of the **default export** of that **module** or **file**. Otherwise throw some error in the code editor.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The bad news is, there is currently no option for this.

The good news is, there is an active PR in [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) for exactly this feature, which only needs to be approved and the feature is ready to go. You can track the PR [here](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/pull/1143).

Comment: The bad news is, the PR is still open in mid 2022

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is use this rule from ESLint: [no-named-as-default](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-named-as-default.md)

You can activate this in your `.eslintrc` file:

```
{"plugins": [ "import" ], "rules": { import/no-named-as-default }}
```

And for more information, you can go to the `import` [page](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import).

Answer (score 0):

## Answering your question directly

In principle, you can write a custom Eslint rule that targets the `ImportDefaultSpecifier` and asserts that the value is some expected value. In order to make this work though, you'd need to enforce some predictable relationship between the default variable and the file name (or something similar) so that your rule can determine whether the imported value is "incorrect" in some way. This opens it's own can of worms and kicks the can down the road a bit because you've now introduced a need for another ESLint rule to enforce the consistent naming convention for exports, and any exceptions will be annoying to deal with.

## My own 2 cents

I'd recommend solving this problem by leveraging the benefits of named exports instead since the main advantage of a default export over a named export is the ability to rename the exported value when importing it elsewhere.

Unless it's too burdensome, I'd suggest the following as a much easier path to what you want.

1. Configure ESlint to enforce only using named exports via the `import/no-default-export` rule and converting your default exports to named exports.
2. Write a custom ESLint rule to detect `import { NamedExport as AliasedExport } from 'source';` statements and disallow them (this is quite easy, I'll show below how to do so)
3. Either publish your rule as package and install and use as normal, or use a plugin like `eslint-plugin-local-rules` so you can import your rule directly.

```
import { ESLintUtils, TSESTree } from '@typescript-eslint/utils';
export const disallowImportAliasing = ESLintUtils.RuleCreator.withoutDocs({
    create(context) {
        return {
            ImportDeclaration(node) {
                const importsWithAlias = node.specifiers.filter(specifier => specifier.local.name !== specifier.imported.name)
                importsWithAlias.forEach(importStatement => {
                    context.report({
                        messageId: 'disallow-import-aliasing',
                        node: importStatement
                    })
                })
            },
        };
    },
    meta: {
        docs: {
            description: 'Our team enforces a requirement to use imported variables exactly as named',
        },
        messages: {
            'disallow-import-aliasing': 'Do not alias imports. Use the imported name as imported',
        },
        type: 'suggestion',
        schema: [],
    },
    defaultOptions: [],
});

export default {
    'disallow-import-aliasing': disallowImportAliasing,
} satisfies Record<string, ESLintUtils.RuleModule<any, any>>;
```